# Remove all but one ( or more ) kind of filetype

Tags: zsh, wildcards

I've been trying to find a command to remove all files in a folder but not a kind of filetype. But I seems to not have any luck. What I've tried so far :

```
set extended_glob
rm !(*.dmg)
# this returns zsh:number expected

rm ./^*.dmg
# this returns no matches found
```

The version of zsh I'm using is `zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.1)` .

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The [`extended_glob`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-EXTENDED_005fGLOB) option gives you zsh's own extended [glob syntax](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators).

```
setopt extended_glob
rm -- ^*.dmg
rm -- ^*.(dmg|txt)
```

This removes files without an extension (e.g. `README`). If you want to keep those files, you can use the `~` operator to limit the matches:

```
setopt extended_glob
rm -- *.*~*.dmg
```

If you want to delete files in subdirectories as well, you can use [`**`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Recursive-Globbing) for recursive globbing. Pass the `.` [glob qualifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to restrict the matching to regular files, or use `^/` instead of `.` to match all non-directories (including e.g. symbolic links). (Note that `rm -r` wouldn't help you since it would either delete a directory and all its contents, or not descend into a directory at all.)

```
rm -- **/^*.(dmg|txt)(.)
```

You can set the [`ksh_glob`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-KSH_005fGLOB) option to get [ksh globs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#ksh_002dlike-Glob-Operators). Beware that in the common case where the negative pattern is the last thing in the word, zsh may [parse the parentheses as glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-BARE_005fGLOB_005fQUAL_002c-use-of) (it doesn't do this in ksh emulation mode).

```
setopt ksh_glob
rm -- !(*.dmg|*.txt)
setopt no_bare_glob_qual
rm -- !(*.dmg)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. When I run `rm -r secrets/!(directory)` it keeps asking for `number expected` or sometimes it gives me `event not found: directory`

Comment: @CMCDragonkai “number expected” indicates that you didn't set the `ksh_glob` option. “event not found: directory” indicates that you're running bash (which also understands the `!(…)` syntax, but only after `shopt -s extglob`).

Comment: How could I be running bash when I was in my zsh shell?

Comment: For me, `setopt ksh_glob; echo !(a|b)` works while `setopt ksh_glob; echo !(a)` doesn't ("number expected")...

Comment: @ThiefMaster I had same issue. Is it a bug?

Comment: @Kabahango It's another complication in zsh parsing: the expression is ambiguous, and zsh favors interpreting the parentheses as glob qualifiers.

Comment: instead of `!(a)` you can use `!(a|)`

Comment: I wanted to delete files recursively. With `set extended_glob` I had to run `rm **/^*(ext1|ext2)`. Folders will still be matched, so do not pass `-rf`!

Comment: @Nico add `(.)` to restrict the matches to regular files, avoid the “cannot remove … Is a directory” error, and also may avoid a disaster if you accidentally pass `-r`.

Comment: All files and subdirectories in directory other than current: `setopt extendedglob; rm -rf dirname/*~*.ext`

Answer (score 8):

You can use `find` instead of your shell:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name "*.dmg" -delete
```

From `man find`:

```
   ! expr True  if  expr  is false.  This character will also usually need
          protection from interpretation by the shell.
   -name pattern
          Base of file name (the path with the leading directories removed)
          matches shell pattern pattern. 
   -delete
          Delete  files; true if removal succeeded.  If the removal failed,
          an error message is issued.  If -delete fails, find's exit status
          will be nonzero (when  it eventually exits).  Use of -delete 
          automatically turns on the -depth option.
```

If you can't use `find` for whatever reason, here's a way to do it with `zsh` (or other shells). `zsh` being `zsh`, there is probably a simpler way of doing this but since I'm a `bash` guy, this is what I came up with:

```
for file in *; do if [[ ! "$file" == *.dmg ]]; then rm $file; fi; done
```

Comment: unfortunately, whenever I use find in my mac, it just exits the current zsh session without any notice. Do you have the same problem ?
`find

[Process completed]`

Comment: @nXqd see updated answer for a way to do it without `find`. I suggest you post a question about your `find` issue though, that should not happen. If you do, include the output of `type -a find`.

Comment: Even in bash, there is a simpler solution: `rm !(*.dmg)`, after `shopt -s extglob`.

Comment: @terdon thanks for your debugging tips in shell. its output seems to be correct : `find is a shell function
find is /usr/bin/find`

Comment: @nXqd that is not correct, it should not be a shell function, it should only be `/usr/bin/find`. You have a function called `find` defined in one of your bash config files. Since you're on OSX, that's probably `~/.profile`.

Comment: @terdon thanks for your comment. I have a malfunction find in my zshrc. just remove it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Another way to remove files is with `find`, `xargs` and `rm`:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name '*.dmg' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also use `fd` ([git-project](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd)) or `fdfind` on debian systems, which has a very **user-friendly** interface.

The command is

```
fd --exclude='*.dmg' --hidden --exec rm
fdfind --exclude='*.dmg' --hidden --exec rm # For Debian systems
fd -E '*.dmg' -H -x rm                      # Short notation
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find  path -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name "*.dmg" -exec rm -vf {} \;
```

Comment: Why not use `+` instead of `\;`? Other than that, could you explain how this is better (if it is) than the other `find`-based solutions which have already been given?