# wildcard negation

Tags: bash, wildcards

How can I get the complementary results of a wildcard expansion?

If I want to list the files that have `roc` in their names, I run

```
ls *roc*
```

but what if I want all the files that do not have `roc` in the name?

`ls *[!r][!o][!c]*` and `ls *[!roc]*`

do not work. There is a simple way to do this "oppposite" expansion?

Note: I'm using `bash`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bash` shell supports extended globbing patterns if you enable them with

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Once enabled, the pattern `!(*roc*)` would match any non-hidden name that does not match `*roc*`, i.e. any name that does not contain the string `roc`.

From the `bash` manual:

> If the `extglob` shell option is enabled using the `shopt` builtin,
> several extended pattern matching operators are recognized.  In the
> following description, a `pattern-list` is a list of one or more
> patterns separated by a `|`.  Composite patterns may be formed using one
> or more of the following sub-patterns:
>
> `?(pattern-list)`
> Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
>
> `*(pattern-list)`
> Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
>
> `+(pattern-list)`
> Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
>
> `@(pattern-list)`
> Matches one of the given patterns
>
> `!(pattern-list)`
> Matches anything except one of the given patterns

Comment: Much simpler that I expected. But so, I looked up, and we have also the solutions for zsh and other shells: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102427/remove-all-but-one-or-more-kind-of-filetype

Answer (score 1):

*Note: this is not what you ask, just a workaround which delivers what you ask*

Usually I reframe the problem, and so I do:

```
ls * | grep -v roc
```

I prefer using common tools (and common command that I use), instead of looking for a thing I'll use probably once a year (and so I'll probably forget).

Working with wildcard may become very complex: different shell have different results, and so it may make scripts non portable.

Comment: Kusalananda's answer is what I was looking for, but I liked your view too. Good reminder!

Comment: Note that this may not do what you expect if you have non-hidden subdirectories in the current directory (or names containing newlines).

Comment: @Kusalananda: right a `ls -d | grep -v roc | xargs ls` is ugly, but comparable (and it allows custom options on last `ls`). Still portable