# How to remove all files in a directory and leave .env?

Tags: bash, wildcards

How can we delete all files inside directory `example/` and not `.env` file?

maybe
`rm -f !(.env) example/` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184956/how-exclude-files-folders-for-remove https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/how-to-exclude-a-directory-in-find-command

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `extglob` and `dotglob` shell options in the `bash` shell with

```bsh
shopt -s extglob dotglob
```

then the pattern `example/!(.env)` would match all names in the `example` directory that is not `.env`.

Note that we need to set `dotglob` to allow globbing patterns to match hidden names.

Using

```bsh
rm -f example/!(.env)
```

would attempt to remove those matching names.

If that pattern expands to too many names you'll get an "argument list too long" error. Running it in a simple loop would be an alternative solution:

```bsh
for name in example/!(.env); do rm -f "$name"; done
```

Related question:

- [wildcard negation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612145)
- [Exclude one pattern from glob match](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164025)